# Invalid Cast Exception but build works fine

Tags: c#, exception, casting

```
public class A
    {
        public void M1()
        {
            Console.Write("Print M1 of Class A");
        }
    }
public class B:A
{
    public void M2()
    {
        Console.Write("Print M2 of Class B");
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public void M3()
    {
        Console.Write("Print M3 of Class C");

    }
}
```

In main method we create objects like:-

```
   A objA = new B();
    B objB = new C();
    A a = new A();
    C objC = (C)a;  /* this line throws runtime error System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'C'.'  but build works fine */

        objA.M1();
        objB.M1();
        objB.M2();
        objC.M1();
        objC.M2();
        objC.M3();
```

I could not cast C to A directly first. Hence tried creating object A then explicit casted it. The intellisense takes it as valid code and build is also fine but during console app execution it throws error "Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'C'."

Comment: Yes, `a` is of (*base*) type `A` and can't be cast to `C` since `C` is *derived* from `A`. The reverse is possible: an object `c` of *derived* class `C` can be cast to *base* class `A`: `C c = new C(); A objA = (A) c;`

Comment: Casts between reference types in the same inheritance tree are "this variable says it's `x` but I know it's really `y`, trust me compiler I know better than you". It doesn't *convert* an `x` into a `y`, you the programmer are asserting that it *always was a `y`* (or something even further derived)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true; you could cast a C to an A any time you want but the only time you can do it the other way round is if you've stored a C in a variable typed as A. The compiler lets you do this because C descends from A, so a variable of type A is capable of holding an instance of type C. Hence, you could have legitimately stored a C in an A and you're casting to get it back to being a C:

```
A reallyC = new C();
C gotBack = (C)reallyC;
```

The compiler doesn't look too hard at what you've done before; it wouldn't see code like this:

```
A reallyA = new A();
C willFail = (C)reallyA;
```

and say "hey; you've stored an A in reallyA, and it can't be cast to a C". It just sees you attempt to cast reallyA to a C and thinks "it could be a C, because a C is a B is an A, so they're related ok.. I trust the dev knows what they're doing and I'll permit it"

Comment: It compiles doesn't mean it's right.  This is a clear example of it.  It's very common to have a C in an A--look at event handlers.  The first parameter is the sender--which is of type object.  Obviously, you'll almost always have to cast it to use it.

Comment: Good point: **everyone writes code all the time that compiles just fine, but is not right**. "Make it, make it go, make it right" - the "make it right" part is called "fixing bugs". Oh, and then make it fast. 

Answer (score 0):

Well, `a` is of (*base*) type `A` and can't be cast to `C` since `C` is *derived* from `A`. The reverse is possible: an object `c` of *derived* class `C` can be cast to *base* class `A`:

```
 C c = new C(); 
 A objA = (A) c;
```

Often we can *try* to cast with a help of `is`:

```
if (a is C objC) {
  // a can be cast to C, objC now holds the result of the cast  
  objC.M3();
}
else {
  // the cast is impossible
}
```